# Sub JComponent Won't gain focus despite visible, enabled being true

Tags: java, focus, japplet

I'm working on a problem and I can't seem to gain focus for JComponent sub components of a Japplet. I'm required to focus the component so that I can use a keyboard listener to register keypresses for a number of onscreen elements (game).

Here's the code:

```
class TestApplet extends JApplet { 
    public void init(){ 
        setSize(400, 800); 
        new test class();
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}


 public class testclass extends JPanel {
 public testclass() {
        grabFocus();
        requestFocus();
        requestFocusInWindow();

       System.out.println("visible: " + isVisible());
        System.out.println("Enbled " + isEnabled());
        System.out.println("Focusable " + isFocusable()); 
        System.out.println(isFocusOwner()); 
    } 
}
```

the output evaluates as

```
visible: true
Enbled true
Focusable true
false
```

This is despite the fact that I've used every possibly comination of focus grabbing for the subcomponent. If I place the same code into the Japplet, the keyboard listener that I create does work but not when I use a subcomponent...

This is fairy critical to my application since I have many JPanels in a hierarchal topography.

N.B it's been suggested that this might be a macosx specific bug - I'm using Intellij CE11.1. Although I'm unable to verify this.

UPDATE: I have to also create the functionality that the program should respond to mb1,2 and the middle mouse button - clearly this is impossible without focus?

Comment: This is yet another reason to strive to avoid using KeyListeners with Swing applications. I'm sure that you've read elsewhere that you should probably be using key bindings instead.

Comment: not before no. I'm looking into the solution at present while perfecting my silly walk. :)

Comment: Consider posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small compilable and runnable applet that requires no outside resources (i.e., images not readily available online) we can run, test and modify, and perhaps help you correct.

Comment: How can I post one of these ? the code above should provide a reproducible test case.

Comment: You would edit your answer and post the code in the edit. The code posted does not demonstrate what you are trying to achieve -- I see no key listener code in there. You are not required to create this, but it does help you get a decent answer quicker. So it all depends on how important it is to get a quick answer.

Comment: The example with keylisteners for w,a,s,d is trivial - the core problem is that I cannot gain focus. Hence the keylistener cannot accept input.

Comment: You may be missing the forest for the trees as key bindings may help eliminate focus issues completely by making it much less important. Again, if I could see a workable sscce, I may be able to help.

Comment: 1) `new test class();` Would not compile.  2) Every applet must be declared as `public` 3) No applet should set its own size, it should be done by HTML. 4) `setVisible(true);` is not required in an applet. 5) `test class` or `testclass` is never added to the applet. 6) Any focus request will fail before the component is made visible.

Answer (score 2):

I created my own SSCCE and on testing, it seems that regardless of what technique is used, the applet still must request and gain focus for them to work. I've gotten this to successfully work on my windows system using either of two kludges, including a javax.swing.Timer that requests focus after xxx ms, or an override of the JApplet's `paint(...)` method that requests focus the first time paint is called (and when the applet is just being rendered).  For example, showing both kludges (only one would be required) and an example of key bindings and of an SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyBindingEg extends JApplet {
   protected static final int TIMER_DELAY = 100;
   private boolean firstPane = true;

   @Override
   public void init() {
      createAndShowGui();
   }

   private void createAndShowGui() {
      try {
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               TestClass test = new TestClass();
               getContentPane().add(test);

               // a kludge to get focus on the GUI some time after it has been created
               new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     requestFocusInWindow();
                     ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                  }
               }).start();
            }
         });
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g);
      // another kludge to get focus on the GUI after it is
      // first rendered
      if (firstPane) {
         requestFocusInWindow();
         firstPane = false;
      }
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TestClass extends JPanel {
   public TestClass() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JLabel("TestClass", SwingUtilities.CENTER));

      int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      for (KeyInfo keyInfo : KeyInfo.values()) {
         KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyInfo.getKeyCode(), 0);
         inputMap.put(keyStroke , keyInfo.toString());
         actionMap.put(keyInfo.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               System.out.println("key press: " + evt.getActionCommand());
            }
         });
      }
   }
}

enum KeyInfo {
   UP(KeyEvent.VK_W), DOWN(KeyEvent.VK_S), LEFT(KeyEvent.VK_A), RIGHT(KeyEvent.VK_D);
   private int keyCode;

   private KeyInfo(int keyCode) {
      this.keyCode = keyCode;
   }

   public int getKeyCode() {
      return keyCode;            
   }

}
```

The above code using an AncestorListener:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class KeyBindingEg extends JApplet {
   protected static final int TIMER_DELAY = 100;
   private boolean firstPane = true;

   @Override
   public void init() {
      createAndShowGui();
   }

   private void createAndShowGui() {
      try {
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               TestClass test = new TestClass();

               JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
               contentPane.add(test);
               contentPane.addAncestorListener(new RequestFocusListener());               
            }
         });
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}

class RequestFocusListener implements AncestorListener {
   public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent arg0) {}
   public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent arg0) {}

   @Override
   public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent aEvt) {
      Component comp = (Component) aEvt.getSource();
      comp.requestFocusInWindow();
   }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TestClass extends JPanel {
   public TestClass() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JLabel("TestClass", SwingUtilities.CENTER));

      int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

      for (KeyInfo keyInfo : KeyInfo.values()) {
         KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyInfo.getKeyCode(), 0);
         inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyInfo.toString());
         actionMap.put(keyInfo.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               System.out.println("key press: " + evt.getActionCommand());
            }
         });
      }
   }
}

enum KeyInfo {
   UP(KeyEvent.VK_W), DOWN(KeyEvent.VK_S), LEFT(KeyEvent.VK_A), RIGHT(
         KeyEvent.VK_D);
   private int keyCode;

   private KeyInfo(int keyCode) {
      this.keyCode = keyCode;
   }

   public int getKeyCode() {
      return keyCode;
   }

}
```

Comment: I suspect an `AncestorListener` as used in [dialog focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) might be effective here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: less kludgy -- I think you're right. I'll try it later and if it works, edit the post. Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand correctly the top level container must gain focus before it's possible to gain focus for the children container and it's ancestors? In my architecture I have more than ten Jpanels linked together... Therefore I hazard a guess that  must force this with a protected void paintComponent() method for one of these sub panels that sets focus upon paint.

Comment: Additional: I've created a top level action listener that's added to the glass pane as a temporary workaround. This is routed through a public interface class to another class that holds the program data and my hope is that I will be able to dispatch these events to there through this hierarchy.

Comment: @peter: No, just use an AncestorListener as Andrew suggested. I have shown an edit/example of this above. Again, you should use Key Bindings which I've also demonstrated above.

Comment: I think this may have been an odd bug of some kind with my implementation - eventually I was able to gain focus within a subcomponent of the main applet.

In the end I settled with using a glass panel to take user input.